# Identity of unknown metal

Tags: metal, identification

I wanted figure out what the identity of this scrap metal was. It seems to be some sheet metal but Wikipedia says sheet metal can be made of a variety of metals. My dad said it might be tin so I thought I'd try and see if it would melt easily since tin melts at a very low temperature. I heated it with a propylene torch but I could only get it red hot. I did notice that it turned yellow when heated and smelled a bit rotten. Any ideas to what this could be?[image][image]

Comment: You could try some simple tests to eliminate some metals.  Is it magnetic? Is it covered with an oxide layer? What is its density (polish then accurately weigh a clean piece; put same into water and accurately measure volume change, calc' density; look up in tables.) File into powder if possible,  try a flame test.  Does it dissolve in acid and alkali?